# how to match matching two datasets

Tags: r

I have a dataset like main.

```
main<-structure(list(name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("AA", "BB", "CC"
), class = "factor"), val1 = c(11L, 22L, 33L), val2 = c(111L, 
222L, 333L)), .Names = c("name", "val1", "val2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I have one more dataset like s1.

```
s1<-structure(list(cname = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("AA", "BB", "CC"), class = "factor"), val1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), val2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("cname", "val1", "val2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

By matching names in main dataset, I have to fill val1 and val2 columns in s1 dataset. 
Now I need output like s2.

```
s2<-structure(list(cname = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("AA", "BB", "CC"), class = "factor"), val1 = c(11L, 
11L, 11L, 22L, 33L, 22L, 22L, 33L, 11L), val2 = c(111L, 111L, 
111L, 222L, 333L, 222L, 222L, 333L, 111L)), .Names = c("cname", 
"val1", "val2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I can do it using for loop. But If I have millions of records, It is very expensive. Is there any other alternative to do this. please help

Comment: Sounds like a job for `merge()`, in which case it would be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right/1300618#1300618).

Comment: @akrun : sometimes slower methods are easier to understand/code/debug and may be preferred over fast but complex methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `data.table` for big datasets

```
 library(data.table)
 d1 <- as.data.table(s1[,1, drop=FALSE])
 setkey(setDT(main), name) 
 main[d1]
 #    name val1 val2
 #1:   AA   11  111
 #2:   AA   11  111
 #3:   AA   11  111
 #4:   BB   22  222
 #5:   CC   33  333
 #6:   BB   22  222
 #7:   BB   22  222
 #8:   CC   33  333
 #9:   AA   11  111
```

#### Benchmarks

On a slightly bigger dataset

```
set.seed(24)
main <- data.frame(name=c(outer(LETTERS, 1:200, FUN= paste0)), 
   val1=sample(1:100, 52e2, replace=TRUE), 
          val2=sample(20:150, 52e2, replace=TRUE))
set.seed(36)
s1 <- data.frame(name= sample(main$name, 1e6, replace=TRUE))

f1 <- function() {s1$id = 1:nrow(s1)
             s2 = merge(main, s1)
             s2 = s2[order(s2$id),]
              }

f2 <- function() {DT <- as.data.table(s1)
              DTmain <- as.data.table(main)
              setkey(DTmain, name) 
              DTmain[DT]
              }
#the `merge` alone function
f3 <- function() {s2 = merge(main, s1)}




library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(),f3(), unit='relative', times=20L)
# Unit: relative
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#f1() 281.9077 239.3932 133.6460 213.5693 88.62224 66.80722    20   b
#f2()   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000  1.00000  1.00000    20  a 
#f3() 272.2257 226.3176 127.0197 204.0454 85.22211 63.79950    20   b
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's useful to me.

Comment: hi akrun, can you provide any alternative for this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924650/how-to-process-huge-amont-of-data-in-less-time?noredirect=1#comment42412615_26924650

Comment: @123456 I will check the post, though can't guarantee to come up something better than your code

Comment: no problem, any way thanks akrun. In that problem no column is depends on other columns(i.e., every column is independent column). I think we can use parallel processing. What I mean is Here we have 4 variables. why don't we process 4 columns in 4 different nodes. Finally combine 4 columns into one dataframe.

Comment: Hi akrun, Do you have any idea on machine learning concepts in r?

Comment: If you have time, can you look at this code please...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924650/how-to-process-huge-amont-of-data-in-less-time?noredirect=1#comment42412615_26924650. Here my problem is, I have to integrate basic machine learning concepts with this code. Can you help me...?

Comment: Hi akrun, I have a user defined function. Now I am using this function in  **optim(pars,myfunction,control = list(trace = TRUE,maxit = 1000))**. Is it possible to convert this optim function into **Rcpp**

Comment: @123456 I am not that experienced in `Rcpp`.  You can post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try merge command:

```
> names(s1)[1]='name'
> merge(main, s1[1])
  name val1 val2
1   AA   11  111
2   AA   11  111
3   AA   11  111
4   AA   11  111
5   BB   22  222
6   BB   22  222
7   BB   22  222
8   CC   33  333
9   CC   33  333
```

To maintain the order:

```
> s1$id = 1:nrow(s1)
> s2 = merge(main, s1[c(1,4)])
> s2 = s2[order(s2$id),]
> s2[1:3]
  name val1 val2
1   AA   11  111
2   AA   11  111
3   AA   11  111
5   BB   22  222
9   CC   33  333
6   BB   22  222
7   BB   22  222
8   CC   33  333
4   AA   11  111
```